# Ideas to speed up this Python script

Tags: python, treeview, tkinter

I wrote a program that walks a directory, moves files into an archive, with the ability to exclude certain paths. It's working, but it's slow.

I couldn't find a way to interact with the items in the ttk.Treeview efficiently so it builds the tree and a dictionary that uses the index from the Treeview as the key and the directory name as the value.

Any ideas on how I could speed this process up?

Right now it takes about 3 minutes to build the directory tree in a decent sized folder and another 3 minutes just to print the new location in testing mode.

My code:

```
import tkFileDialog, os, ttk, checkage, logging, shutil
from Tkinter import *
import profile

source = ''
dest = ''

#Build UI
class Master(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)         
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("pyRchive")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        lSrc = Label(self, text="Choose Source Directory")
        lSrc.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 2, pady = 2, sticky=NW)
        eSrc = Entry(self, bd=5, width=50)
        eSrc.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky=SW)
        bSrc = Button(self, text="Browse...", command=lambda: choosedir(eSrc))
        bSrc.grid(column = 1, row = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky=SW)
        bAdd = Button(self, text="Add", command=lambda: buildTree(self))
        bAdd.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky=NW)
        lDest = Label(self, text="Choose Destination Directory")
        lDest.grid(column = 0, row = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky=NW)
        eDest = Entry(self, bd=5, width=50)
        eDest.grid(column = 0, row = 2, padx = 2, pady = 5, sticky=SW)
        bDest = Button(self, text="Browse...", command=lambda: choosedir(eDest))
        bDest.grid(column = 1, row = 2, padx = 2, pady = 5, sticky=SW)
        bExec = Button(self, text="Archive Files", command=lambda: archive(self))
        bExec.grid(column = 0, row = 3, padx = 2, pady = 5, sticky=NW)
        bDel = Button(self, text="Remove Directory", command=lambda: deldir(self))
        bDel.grid(column = 1, row = 9, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky=SE)
        tree = ttk.Treeview(self, height=20)
        tree.column("#0", width=400)
        tree.grid(column = 2, row = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, rowspan=10, sticky=NSEW)

        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL, command=tree.yview)
        tree['yscroll'] = ysb.set
        ysb.grid(in_=self, column = 3, row=0, sticky=NS, rowspan=10)
        rootlst = {}

        #Display Directory when bBrowse is pressed
        def choosedir(text):
            logging.info('Adding Directory to %s' %(text))
            rootfolder = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
            text.insert(0, os.path.abspath(rootfolder))

        #Build the Directory Tree
        def buildTree(self):
            logging.info('Building Directory Tree')
            rootfolder = eSrc.get()
            global source
            source = rootfolder
            create_root(rootfolder)
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootfolder):        
                for i in rootlst:
                    if os.path.split(root)[0] == rootlst[i]:
                        logging.info('Adding %s to directory tree' %(root))
                        rt = tree.insert(i, 'end', text='\\' + os.path.basename(root))
                        rootlst[rt] = root
                        break
            eSrc.delete(0, 'end')
            #print tree.get_children()

        #Make root level of tree
        def create_root(root):
            logging.info('Adding the root directory (%s) to the tree' %(root))
            rt = tree.insert('', 'end', text=root)
            rootlst[rt] = root

        #Archive the files in the selected directories
        def archive(self):
            logging.info('Starting Archive Process')
            dest = eDest.get()
            if os.path.isdir(source):
                for i in rootlst:                    
                    for fname in os.listdir(rootlst[i]):
                        oldname = os.path.join(rootlst[i], fname)
                        if os.path.isfile(oldname):
                            logging.info('fname is a file')
                            if checkage.check(oldname):
                                logging.info('fname is older than 3 years')
                                newname = oldname.replace(source, dest)
                                logging.info('Moving %s to %s' %(oldname, newname))
                                print newname

            else:
                pass
                #put a message box here for invalid Destination Directory

        #Remove Directories from tree
        def deldir(self):
            selected = tree.selection()
            sel = []
            for i in selected:
                path = rootlst[i]
                print 'Delete ', tree.item(i, 'text'), ' and all sub directories'
                print path

                tree.delete(i)
                for i in rootlst:
                    if rootlst[i].startswith(path):
                        sel.append(i)
                for i in sel:
                    del rootlst[i]
            for i in rootlst:
                print i

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='pyRchive.log', format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('Starting Application')
    root = Tk()
    app = Master(root)
    root.mainloop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You could try to find out what is slow: walking the directories, or populating the tree view. (Comment out the lines that insert to tree and see how the runtime changes)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion and it seems to be the walking that takes time. I suppose that means there isn't really anything I can do about this? Is there a better way to build a directory tree with the ability to remove directories from the list? Well I don't necessarily need to remove directories from the list I just need to exclude them from the 'Archive' process

Comment: You could measure where you REALLY loose time. Easiest way would be to put some `t=time.time()` and print `t-time()` somewhere at the crucial places! And don't underestimate the overhead of the print statement itself! for loops and long lists are also possible suspects. Try to determine where you really loose time and then come back! Feel free to adapt you original question (not change it's original direction) to reflect your narrowing down process! Good hunting! ;-)

Comment: I did what you suggested and used `t-time()` and just to `os.walk` the directories and add all the sub-directories to a list takes 115 seconds. That was for a total of 7895 directories. mguijarr's response sounds a lot faster than what I am doing, however, I don't know how I could implement that and still be able to accomplish my goal. At some point I'm going to have to use `os.walk` any way to check the age of every file. Could this be done some other way that I am overlooking?

Comment: You can do what I said in my answer for the *display*, then once user has selected the directories to backup, you can selectively check for the age of files (using os.walk or whatever you want) as pre-backup operation, not in the UI.

Comment: That should work. Is there a way that you know of to get the directory directly from Treeview? Basically right now I have to do every operation twice. Once in the tree and once in the dictionary that keeps up with the Treeview index and the directory that it refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `os.walk` ; instead, use `os.listdir` to get the first level entries,
then build your tree and only on demand (when user selects a directory) you execute
another `os.listdir` of the required directory and display its contents, etc.

You do a lazy evaluation of the directory contents depending on user's actions
instead of making a big structure in advance.